# Meaning of "commit"

Tags: meaning

> No one knows anything – and even that’s not certain. You shouldn’t
>   rely on what you believe to be true. You might be mistaken. Everything
>   can be questioned, everything doubted. The best option, then, is to
>   keep an open mind. Don’t **commit**, and you won’t be disappointed. That
>   was the main teaching of Scepticism, a philosophy that was popular for
>   several hundred years in Ancient Greece and later in **Rome**.

[A little history of Philosohphy, Nigel Warburton, p. 16]

What does "commit" in the context mean? I think It means "promise", is it right?

And How about he word "Rome". Is it referring to the city of Rome or Roman Empire? I am so confused.

Comment: "Don't commit yourself strongly to any opinion". Don't become entrenched in any creed or opinion. (Of course "Roman Empire")

Answer (score 2):

If you commit to do something, you form a firm intention to do it. A promise implies that are now obligated to someone else to do it. A commitment can be entirely one-sided.

This quote uses commit somewhat differently. It refers to committing to *ideas*. You can, for instance, commit yourself to a particular religion if you decide to never stop believing in it. That's the kind of commitment referred to here.

And to answer your last question, "Rome" here is shorthand for the Roman Empire, not the city of Rome.